# How to create silent install using Winrar for Setup program 'Run after installation'

Tags: exe, winrar, winzip, sfx

I can create normal silent executable by selecting 'Hide all' option in Silent mode through SFX options. 
But when I add file in SFX options -> Setup program ->'Run after extraction' e.g. devnode.exe
devnode.exe does not run silently.
Is there way to run setup file silently?

Answer (score 0):

Windows opens automatically a console window if `devnode.exe` is a console application and not a Windows (GUI) application. This can't be avoided. Only Windows application can be executed without showing a window if the application is coded not opening a window on execution.

However, usually it is good practice to show a user executing a self-extracting archive what is going on. The requirement of a completely hidden installation using a self-extracting archive is something mainly bad guys need.

A good installation of an application which need to run a console application is done best with running a batch file after extracting the files showing with 1 or more echo messages what happens now before running the console application from within the batch file and delete with last line in batch file the batch file itself.

Example of such a setup/install batch file:

```
@echo off
rem Set title for the console window.
title Installation of XXX
rem Output information for the user.
echo Installing XXX, please wait ...
rem Call the console application which completes the installation.
devnode.exe
rem Delete this batch file as not needed anymore.
del %0
```

Note: The batch file is executed always with surrounding double quotes and therefore `%0` is a string containing already double quotes at beginning and end. So it would be wrong to use double quotes around `%0` in the last line.